# Records get skipped Due to timeZone difference between Server and cllients in Nodejs Rethinkdb?

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, rethinkdb

iam filtering some records from my Rethinkdb . the code works just fine  when i use the following  code . but  it  works  with date  only

```
(new Date(filter.fromdate+' 00:00 GMT+00:00'));
```

the line above  works perfect  even after  the  server is on different  region. By using above . It  wont skipp any records  and  time and  date just works fine .

but  when i  use  date with time it  throws error  of **rangeError invalid time**
I am saving date in rethink in the following format **Mon Feb 20 2017 07:25:27 GMT+00:00**

SomeHow i just need  time with my  date  to work with the above  mentioned code or may be other  method can also be used .

Comment: Maybe using unixtimestamp can help you, later handle it with moment.js and format properly

Comment: Can you explain more  or provide me  example or  some link regarding the question

Comment: Ok im outside the office , 30 minutes I put an example code

Comment: yeah sure i will be looking forward

Comment: ok i re-read your question, maybe you are doing the follow? date+time+time?

Comment: yeah   thats  the  problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to check if `filter.fromdate` is with time:
If with time don't add your time and modify it with the proper method of Date , otherwise if is a date without time add your time. And remember you can use momentjs instead of Date to handle dates. Hope help you man.

Comment: yes  **filter.fromdate** is with time  .  i think should take a look at momentjs